# Settings.ini in same folder as application is write protect

Tags: qt, qsettings

I made a little tool application and it accesses Settings.ini via QSettings. The ini file I put in the same directory as the application itself. But when I try to write to it using the application, it seems to be blocked due to no admin access. I am guessing the Program Files (x86) folder is offlimits to write? Thus how do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guess correctly, it is most likely a permission problem.  Typically user settings files go into a user-accessible folder separate from the application itself, for example `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Company\Application.ini` on Windows.

All you really need to enable a .ini settings file for your application is something like this (from [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details) docs):

```
QSettings settings("MySoft", "Star Runner");
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::IniFormat);
```

On Windows this will automatically create/use: `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\MySoft\Star Runner.ini` for all future `QSettings` calls.

(And works automatically on other platforms as well.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will check this when I get back home.